# SSL on AWS? Cert installed but still having issues

Tags: linux, security, ssl, certificate-authority

We bought an SSL certificate (From Comodo) and when I visit the page in Chrome I see the green padlock and it has the following information:

```
Your connection to ...... is encrypted with 128-bit encryption.

The connection uses TLS 1.2.

The connection is encrypted and authenticated using AES_128_GCM and uses RSA as the key exchange mechanism.
```

Above that there is the following information:

```
The identity of this website has been verified by EssentialSSL CA but does not have public audit records.
```

The problem is that requests coming from Android devices, PHP (cURL), PLC's, etc all get certificate warnings and in turn the requests do not process.  In some cases you can ignore the warnings however that is bad practice and is also not possible in all scenarios.  I am at a loss for what is wrong but I would love some insight into what exactly the problem is and how to go about fixing it.  My understanding is that Comodo is a root CA so I am not sure what the issue is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you combine the certs correctly? https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_a=viewarticle&_m=knowledgebase&kbarticleid=1365

It sounds a bit like that could be the issue

Comment: This was correct!  We used an online tool (http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html) to find out what the problem was and then we got it corrected.

Comment: Glad to hear that you were able to solve it! https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ is also pretty helpful in case you want to check your cert chain or ciphers.